# Nancy FX enable CORS for static content

Tags: cors, nancy

I'm able to allow CORS for my ordinary routes, but not for static content, because the after request pipeline handler is not called for those requests.

Any way to enable it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. There are at least a couple ways to solve it. I was able to remove the "/Content" directory from the static conventions and handle those requests in a NancyModule, then the AfterPipeline handlers are run. Another option is to move the files that require CORS out of the "/Content" directory to another location, and handle those requests in a NancyModule.

Here's an example, starting in a custom bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(Nancy.Conventions.NancyConventions nancyConventions)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);

    //remove "/Content" directory from the static conventions
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Clear();

    //add a different path to static content since it is not allowed to be empty
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("scripts"));            
}
```

And in a NancyModule, handle the file requests, perhaps like...

```
Get["/content/{path*}"] = args =>
{
    var path = "/content/" + args.path;

    //pass in the file path, and content type to return
    return Response.AsFile(path, "text/plain");
};
```

If you just move the files out of the "/Content" directory, then just replace `content` with the alternative folder name, i.e. `Get["/altFolder/{path}*"]` and `var path = "/altFolder/" + args.path;`.